# How to animate JLabel and not push other components

Tags: java, forms, swing

I'm trying to animate the JLabel, when i'm setting it visible true. And when my JLbael is showing up, other components are pushed down. Is there any way to keep jlabel in one position when visible and not visible? I'm using gridbaglayout.

Comment: Please describe your problem in greater detail. When adding a component to a container that uses a layout manager and that holds other components, it is to be expected that the layout manager might move things around, and this suggests to me that we may have an XY Problem here, one where the solution to the overall problem is completely different from what you're trying to do, which is why it is so important for you to tell us your overall problem too. For instance, perhaps you want to do your animation in the glasspane and not in your JPanel -- but at present I don't know enough to rec this.

Comment: You could create a custom componet, extending from JLabel, witch has and alpha value instead, so the component could always be visible, the animate the alpha value. You would need to override the paintComponent method and use a AlphaComposite to achieve it

Answer (score 3):

The `visible` state of a component will affect how most layout managers will treat the component, typically, they ignore them when they aren't visible.

You could write your own layout manager, but that's kind of annoying and time consuming.  You could use a "fake" component (adding the label inside it), but that's kind of messy and hard to keep the two components in sync or you could "fake" the visibility state...

Start by creating a custom component which extends from `JLabel`, override it's `paintComponent` and using a `AlphaComposite` change the transparency level of the content which is painted.  This way, you could animate the "alpha" level instead of the visibility level...

[image: Rabbit]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private FadeLabel fadeLabel;
        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            fadeLabel = new FadeLabel("Rabbit");
            fadeLabel.setAlpha(0f);

            add(new JLabel("Watch me pull a..."), gbc);
            add(fadeLabel, gbc);

            JButton btn = new JButton("out of my hat");
            add(btn, gbc);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                        fadeLabel.setAlpha(0);
                        timer.start();
                    }
                }
            });

            timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    float alpha = fadeLabel.getAlpha();
                    alpha += 0.01;
                    if (alpha >= 1.0f) {
                        alpha = 1.0f;
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                    fadeLabel.setAlpha(alpha);
                }
            });

        }

    }

    public class FadeLabel extends JLabel {

        private float alpha = 1f;

        public FadeLabel(String text, Icon icon, int horizontalAlignment) {
            super(text, icon, horizontalAlignment);
        }

        public FadeLabel(String text, int horizontalAlignment) {
            super(text, horizontalAlignment);
        }

        public FadeLabel(String text) {
            super(text);
        }

        public FadeLabel(Icon image, int horizontalAlignment) {
            super(image, horizontalAlignment);
        }

        public FadeLabel(Icon image) {
            super(image);
        }

        public FadeLabel() {
        }

        public float getAlpha() {
            return alpha;
        }

        public void setAlpha(float value) {
            if (value != alpha) {
                float old = alpha;
                this.alpha = value;
                firePropertyChange("alpha", old, alpha);
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(alpha));
            super.paintComponent(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Now, you can just as easily set the alpha level from 0 to 1 and you will get the same instance change as you would if you changed the visibility state, but without the bumping of surrounding components